# Invisible type signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to use ambiguous type `a` in function as follows, but it fails.

```
foo :: (Read a, Show a) => IO ()
foo = print =<< (readLn :: IO a)
```

The purpose is to get different outputs regarding to the given type signature when actually called.

```
>>> foo :: Double => IO ()
34   -- user input
34.0 -- output

>>> foo :: Int => IO ()
34   -- user input
34   -- output
```

How can I manage this?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the sample function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is to manifest your type variable. For example, using a newish GHC:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
foo :: forall proxy a. (Read a, Show a) => proxy a -> IO ()
foo _ = print (read "34" :: a)
```

Then, in ghci:

```
Data.Proxy *Main> foo (Proxy :: Proxy Double)
34.0
Data.Proxy *Main> foo (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
34
```

Or, a more exotic usage, relying on more implicit Haskell behavior:

```
*Main> foo [0.0]
34.0
*Main> foo [0]
34
```

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` is what I wanted!
Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can do this without `ScopedTypeVariables`, e.g. define `asProxyTypeOf :: a -> proxy a -> a; asProxyTypeOf = const` and then write ``foo p = print (read "34" `asProxyTypeOf` p)``.

Comment: And with SignatureSections you can write `foo (:: Int) 34`.

Answer (score 4):

Neither `foo :: Double => IO ()` nor `foo :: Int => IO ()` are valid signatures, since `Double` and `Int` aren't constraints.

However, you could easily make the function polymorphic in its return type and write it the following way:

```
foo :: (Read a, Show a) => IO a
foo = let x = read "34" in print x >> return x
```

That way, you can use `foo :: IO Double` or `foo :: IO Integer`:

```
ghci> foo :: IO Double
34.0 -- print
34.0 -- result, you would discard it
ghci> foo :: IO Integer
34
34
```

Comment: Sorry, but It's not I intended to do.
The type should be `IO ()`

Comment: @user3749167: That's easily fixable with `void (foo :: ...)`. The other variant would be `ScopedTypeVariables`, as Daniel said.

Comment: My actual function is far more complicated, and it can't be resolved with `void`.
Thanks a lot!